# Botón siguiente y anterior en java

Tags: java, array, botón

No sé cómo hacer que cuando el botón siguiente tenga un valor del vector, me guarde la posición y no me mande error cuando trato de devolverlo desde donde quedo.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Taller2 {
int cont = 0;

    Vector<String> Anuncio = new Vector<String>();//aqui creo el vector tipo String
    
    int UltPos;//esta es la variable con la que quiero guardar la ultima posicion

    public void adicionar() { //aqui es para adicionar valores al vector por medio del usuario
        String entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese una palabra :");
        String Palabra = (entrada);
        Anuncio.add(Palabra);
    }

    public void Siguiente() { //el metodo para recorrer el vector hacia adelante 1 a 1
        if (cont != Anuncio.size()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Anuncio.get(cont).toString());
            cont++;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay mas");
        }
        UltPos = UltPos + cont;
    }

    // Llama el valor anterior del vector  
    public void Anterior() { //ESTE METODO ES EL QUE NO FUNCIONA Y NO SE COMO DEVOLVERLO
        if (UltPos >= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Anuncio.get(UltPos).toString());
            UltPos--;
        }else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no hay mas");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Un consejo: no uses Vector, usa ArrayList. Vector es una clase vieja de Java que no aporta nada y es más lenta a la hora de acceder o insertar que ArrayList

Comment: Por otro lado ¿Qué error tienes?

Comment: la clase vector es el requisito que pide el tutor, ademas el error es que despues de que presiono el boton anterior solo me muestra el primer valor.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo que hago es esto :

```
  Nombredelaclase n= new Nombredelaclase ();
        n.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
```

**Nombredelaclase n= new Nombredelaclase ();** eso hace que nos mande a la pagina que queramos ir ya sea una mas hacia delante o hacia atrás poniendo el nombre de la clase.

**n.setVisible(true);** mostramos la clase a la cual vamos a ir en mi caso `Nombredelaclase`

**this.dispose();** Cierra la ventana actual

Comment: El problema es que necesito devolverlo de esa manera por que es el requisito, no se si lo que me mandaste sea aplicable al vector. Ej: vector (casa, carro, arbol, pato)
ahi necesito que cuando siguiente llegue al valor "pato" y use el boton anterior comience a devolverse en orden.

Comment: pues entonces no lo se lo siento